# How can I troubleshoot what is causing 'Android OS' to eat up lots of battery?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, battery-life, troubleshooting

Are there steps I can take to rule things out eventually leading to a root cause?

I am currently using the latest Dirty Unicorn ROM on a Nexus 5.

For the same of argument, consider the case where the phone is down to 50% and 'Android OS' was responsible for 25-35% of that drain and the 'Screen' was responsible for the bulk of the remainder.

Typically I would expect to see ~25% Screen drain after a good bit of usage but AOS would not also account for that + some. In my case, I am seeing twice as much drain as I would typically see due to this.

I am suspecting it is due to an always connected VPN but I would like to be able to get definitive evidence. The VPN app process is using a negligible amount of CPU.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'lots of battery'? I know that sounds like  a silly qustion, but if you leave your phone with the screen off (and wifi / mobile data etc off) then SOMETHING has to be running on the device, and that is the Android OS that will show on battery stats. A high **percentage** is not the same as it eating a lot of battery. As in it could use 90% of the battery STATS but since you weren't using it that's not much, and could be only 1% of the **actual charge** of the battery. It could well be the kernel on that ROM if it is just draining like mad.

Comment: Right. Added some specifics. What I am getting at is above average utilization solely by the AOS process (many sub-processes) while also draining the battery at an above idle rate. Regardless of that however, my main question is really about figuring out which sub-process(s) are doing the draining.